# take div's id by referencing this

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone im trying to get the `id` of a `div` through a `function` in `javascript` like this:

```
<div id="txtHint" onload="getId(this);"></div>
```

The function is located just before `</body>` tag of my `html` page

```
function getId(theId) {
    var name = document.getElementById(theId);
}
```

In the body of my `html` page i have a `button`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert(getId())">get</button>
```

I receive an `undefined` `alert` on clicking

How do i get the `div's id`?
Anyone can help?

Comment: add your function `getId` to the post

Comment: `this` or `theId` in your funtion is the `<div>` element and not only its `id` property

Comment: how does your `getId` function look like ?

Comment: so to take the id how to do it?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey The second (not inline) code block in the question

Comment: simply get `theId.id` in your function

Comment: What you actually want to do? Elaborate please

Comment: alert not working when referencing the function on click of button

Comment: i have more div's and im triyng to take thier id names with a function

Comment: Which `<div>` element's `id` you want to `alert`  with that `function`. Because `button` is only 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I don't know the use case of this, you can pass the id to the function and return that from the function:

```js
function getId(theId) {
  var name = document.getElementById(theId);
  return name.id;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtHint"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="alert(getId('txtHint'))">get</button>
```

**Update:** If you want to get all id's by tag, simple pass the tag to the function and get all the id's of those element:

```js
function getId(el) {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  var id = [...element].map(i=>i.id).filter(i=>i);
  return id;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtHint1">First</div>
<div id="txtHint2">Second</div>
<div id="txtHint3">Third</div>
<div id="txtHint4">Fourth</div>

<button type="button" onclick="alert(getId('div'))">get</button>
```

Comment: yeah it's weird getting id of a div when you already know it. Simply write this id inside your function, right? `alert('ImID')`

Comment: @line88, yes, you are right....that why I mentioned about the use case in the answer.....though, I have added another solution...thanks.

Comment: is not weird im using in a loop

Comment: @andrew06041990, that's really grate to know:)

Answer (score 1):

The way your functions is written the only way is to have global `variable`

```
var divId = null;
function getId(div) {
   divId = div.id;
}

function getId() {
  alert(divId);
}
```

And here is my suggetions on doing it

First way is to "mark" the div at `onload` event and get the id of it using this "mark"

```js
function markDiv(thisDiv) {
  thisDiv.classList.add('mark')
}

function getMarkedDiv() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.mark');
  alert(div.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="Mark" onload="markDiv(this)" class="mark"></div>

<button onclick="getMarkedDiv()">button</button>
```

Another way is to wrap the `button` and the `div` inside one parent

```js
function getMySiblingId(button) {
  alert(button.parentElement.firstElementChild.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <div id="Mark"></div>
  <button onclick="getMySiblingId(this)">Button</button>
</div>
```

**Or the easiest way is to wrap button inside the desired div**

```js
function getId(btn) {
  alert(btn.parentElement.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="Mark">
  <button onclick="getId(this)">Click me</button>
</div>
<div id="Alice">
  <button onclick="getId(this)">Click me</button>
</div>
<div id="Charlie">
  <button onclick="getId(this)">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Of course in all this scenarios i didn't assume that you want to get ids of multiple divs

Answer (score 0):

so i remade the code

```
function divField(theDivFieldId) {
  var name = document.getElementById(theDivFieldId);
  return name.id;
}
```

html

```
<div id="txtHint" onload="alert(divField(this));"></div>
```

and nothing happens

Comment: You should not your code here. Just edit it in the main post